# Extract group id string from powershell azure

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory, azure-powershell

I'm have some groups on azure, which I'm retriving with Get-AzADGroup like so:

**Get-AzADGroup -Filter "startsWith(DisplayName, 'groupname')"**

which yields the displayname, the id, the mailnickname and the discription..

What I want to do is to get the ID only and put it into a variable. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To return only specific properties, you can pipe the results into `Select-Object` and specify which properties

```
$variable = Get-AzADGroup -Filter "startsWith(DisplayName, 'groupname')" | Select-Object Id
```

Alternatively, you can store the entire results in the variable, and use dot-notation to get a specific property

```
$variable = Get-AzADGroup -Filter "startsWith(DisplayName, 'groupname')"

$variable.Id
```

Answer (score 0):

I spent all day in Graph doing this very thing.
Eight hours and four lines of code. I love my work.

If it were me, I would try,

`(Get-AzADGroup -Filter "startsWith(DisplayName, 'groupname')").ID`